# Ubuntu 16.04 Login loop after increasing partition size

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, login

[CLOSED]I followed all the forums there are and successfully extended my root partition by removing some chunk of memory from windows. Everything worked perfectly before I tried to login for the first time and got stuck in a login loop. Now, I have also read all the possible solutions to fixing boot loop but none of them worked for me. I was wondering if this was a new issue? Any expert could come up with a trick to get me past this? 
Note: I don't have Nvidia graphics.
Massive thanks!

Comment: "Boot loop" means that the computer reboots, but you also specify that the problem began only after attempting a login. Although it's conceivable that logging in would trigger a reboot, this would be very unusual. Please clarify precisely what happens. If you turn on the computer, walk away, and return in an hour, will it have rebooted multiple times while you're away? Does it reboot only if you log in? Does the computer remain booted, but log you out, when you log in? (Rebooting is *not* the same as logging you out!)

Comment: Ah! I only meant "Login loop". There is no boot looping involved, I was probably in two minds then, my bad. 
I have also re-installed ubuntu since asking this question and the problem still persists. (I was able to login for the first time after the re-install ONLY). 
I am able to login with my guest user and a newly created user from the shell.

Comment: When you re-installed, did you preserve your home directory (or `/home` partition, if it's separate)? If so, then that suggests there's a bad configuration file that's causing the login to fail. The easiest solution is likely to be to create a new account and use it instead, at least as a temporary measure. If you wiped everything, including your home account, then my guess is that some normal login process, like adjusting the display resolution, is failing in a spectacular way. If you installed 16.04 GA, you might try with 16.04.2 instead.

Comment: No, I did not preserve anything from my previous install. It most definitely is a config file problem yes. I've been using a newly created account for a few days but I can't seem to get any sudo rights. I can't manage to change the sudoers file because it requires you to login as the superuser. I'm in such a mess!

Comment: You can hit <Ctrl+Alt+F2> to get a text-mode login prompt, use that to login as your normal user, and edit the `/etc/sudoers` file with a text-mode editor. When you're done, hit <Alt+F7> to get back to the GUI.

Comment: You can't open a text mode editor from the command prompt login (Ctrl+Alt+F2) window. There's no graphical support apparently. I might well be typing the wrong commands. Do you have some specific command(s) that will let me edit /etc/sudoers from the text login window?

Comment: There are plenty of text-mode editors you can use, such as `vi`, `emacs`, and `nano`. Some of these are difficult to use, and some may not be installed by default; but they are all options, and numerous Web sites describe how to use them.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that I can't open any of these text editors from inside the text mode login screen (Ctrl+Alt+F2). I'm actually considering re-installing again. This is just disappointing. Do you have any links you could provide me? Say to use ANY editor from the text mode login screen.

Comment: I did it! Just typed "visudo" and edited the sudoers file. Funny because i was doing the same thing earlier too. Anyway, thanks for all the help @RodSmith really appreciate it! :)